# Get element of the object in PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, joomla

So I got this array with associative object in PHP and I couldnot figure out how to get specific element
here is an array:

```
extra_fields => [
                {"id":"1","value":"1055"},
                {"id":"2","value":"Link"},
                {"id":"3","value":"Name"}
                ]
```

I tried like this but it doesn't work
`extra_fields[0]["value"])` and `extra_fields[0]->value`

Please help.
UPDATE:
full output code:

```
    stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 723
        [title] => XXXXXXX
        [alias] => XXXXXXX
        [catid] => 50
        [published] => 1
        [introtext] =>  
        [fulltext] => 
        [video] => 
        [gallery] => 
        [extra_fields] => [
                {"id":"1","value":"1055"},
                {"id":"2","value":"Link"},
                {"id":"3","value":"Name"}
                ]
     )
```

this is an `$item` coming out of Joomla CMS K2 plugin when I use `print_r()` command
I can access normal stuff like this `$item->title` and get `XXXXXXX` for my value, but could not figure out how to get items from `extra_fields`

Comment: This is not a valid PHP object. Is `extra_fields` an array or a JSON string?

Comment: Please show your full code. what is your logic?  `extra_fields[0]["value"]` is correct.

Comment: Share full code , how you get this output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was pretty simple, I used json_decode() function to convert it too array

```
    $someArray = json_decode($item->extra_fields, true);
                    print_r($someArray[0]["value"]);
```

Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0):

as others mentioned, this doesn't seem valid PHP data, however if you would convert array of objects to multidimensional array, then do it this way:-

```
<?php 
// new var that holds the arrays
$multiArray = [];
foreach ($extra_fields as $field){
$multiArray[] = (array) $field;
}
// now this var has the exact data that you want...
print_r($mulitArray);
```

Hope this helps.